# Offsetting an existing date value, where values exist in another column in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to offset an existing date (in this case by 2 months), based on a value in another column (Type).

```
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Lock', 'Start'] = df['Start'] + pd.DateOffset(months=-2)

Error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Can this be accomplished in one line like I've tried? If not, what other approaches are there?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Start'] = np.where(df['Type'] == 'Lock',
                        df['Start'] + pd.DateOffset(months=-2),
                        df['Start'])
```